# how to load YAML config file in scala to convert it into CSV along with XML file which has raw data

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, yaml

I have the XML file which is a raw file and I have a YAML config file with `rowtags` and its values are in XML file only. I want to produce a CSV file in Scala by using both of the above files. How can I do that in Scala?

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream}
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor
import java.util.Map;

case class data (employee: String)

var yamlData = 
   spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles( "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/forex_sample.yml")
     .map(x => x._2)
     .collect()(0)

val yaml = new Yaml()
var config = 
      yaml.load(yamlData)
        .asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]
var item = config.get("employee")
println("item")
print (config)
```

Comment: Fixed code layout, typos.

Comment: Fixed some more typos. The recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2006, maybe it is time by now to follow the recommendation.